# Word 2016 Printing background colour

Tags: microsoft-word, printing, colors

I want to print a document including the background colour.

I can get the background colour fine, but there is a coloured box around all text and images - like a highlight on screen.

This isn't visible in the print preview.

Does anyone have any ideas?[image: issue]

Comment: Clear the formatting of the text with unwanted color content. Re-format your text again, if needed. https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Clear-all-text-formatting-c094c4da-7f09-4cea-9a8d-c166949c9c80 I hope this will solve the problem!

Answer (score 0):

It was the printer driver for the Ricoh multifunction.

Under finishing, I changed from 'vector' to 'raster' and the issue was solved.